# Premix glucosamine - Impact of storage on effectiveness

Tags: dogs, medicines

I started giving my 9 year old golden retriever cosequin recently for stiffness. She had tibial-plateau-leveling osteotomy (TPLO) surgery when she was 3.

To get her to eat it, I grind up the pills and mix it in with a small amount of yogurt or tuna twice a day.

Would it impact the effectiveness to mix the morning and night batches at the same time and leave one in the fridge all day?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would advise against it. 
I am not familiar with the typical bacteria living and growing in a can of tuna after opening it, but with the yogurt, the bacteria in there will metabolize the glucosamine. This will definitively impact the effectiveness. I strongly suspect this would at least to some extent also happen with the tuna.

[Here](http://pubmedcentralcanada.ca/pmcc/articles/PMC242922/pdf/aem00219-0157.pdf) is one example of Lactobacillus bacteria able to ferment glucosamine. I did not add this before because using glucosamine as a nutrient is not uncommon in general for bacteria (like it is not for humans or dogs).

Comment: Do you have any references supporting your claim that yogurt cultures will metabolize the glucosamine?

Comment: "bacteria in yogurt" are not necessarily just the yogurt cultures, but anything that likes lactic acid. Metabolizing glucosamine is not uncommon in those, as far as I remember. (In fact more like that common that it is not specifically published anymore.)